# How to use DirichletCondition with DSolve and not just NDSolveValue?

Tags: differential-equations, regions

I know one can use `Region` and `DirichletCondition` with `NDSolveValue`. But I do not know why it does not work with `DSovle`.

Here is an example. Laplace PDE over square with only bottom edge having non zero `DirichletCondition`. Same code works OK with `NDSolveValue` but not with `DSolve` nor with `DSolveValue`.  So I must be doing something wrong or it is not supported with `DSolve`?

```
pde = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
region = Region[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]];
bc = Piecewise[{{Sin[x], 0 <= x <= 1 && y == 0}, {0, 
     0 <= y <= 1 && x == 1}, {0, 0 <= x <= 1 && y == 1}, {0, 
     0 <= y <= 1 && x == 0}}];
dcond = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == bc, True];
sol = DSolve[{pde, dcond}, u, Element[{x, y}, region]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Same code works if I change `DSolve` to `NDSolveValue`

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, dcond}, u, Element[{x, y}, region]];
Plot3D[sol[x, y], Element[{x, y}, region]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`DSolve` can solve it by specifying boundary conditions the normal way and without using region:

```
ClearAll[u, x, y];
pde = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
bc = {u[x, 0] == Sin[x], u[1, y] == 0, u[x, 1] == 0, u[0, y] == 0};
sol = DSolve[{pde, bc}, u[x, y], x, y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The question is: Why using `DirichletCondition`  and `Region` did not work with `DSolve` nor `DSolveValue`? Is this supposed to be used only with numerical solver? I have feeling these are meant for numerical solver only, but wanted to make sure. I could not find this info doing some google search.

Using version 11.3 on windows 10.

Comment: Note that there's an example of `DirichletCondition` being used with `DSolveValue` in the documentation for `DirichletCondition`.  So the real question is why this doesn't work for your particular case.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes, I also tried DSolveValue and it did not work there. I'll edit my question and also mention that. Thanks.

Comment: My point is that there are known examples where `DSolve` or `DSolveValue` can use `DirichletCondition`, and that one such example is in the documentation.  So it's not the case that `DirichletCondition` is unsupported by the exact PDE solvers;  the real question is which types of problems it *can* be invoked for.  Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I see. I must have overlooked that example. I did look at those help pages, but there are so many of them. I did not see one using DirichletCondition and DSolveValue or DSolve that is why I asked. Ok then the question should be as you said, why it does not work for this one. I'll go now and do better search for that example you mentioned.

Comment: Playing around with things a little more, `DSolve` appears to be able to solve for `DirichletCondition`s in terms of `Piecewise` functions on the unit disk (though it takes a long time).  I suspect that it may only be implemented for this particular domain for some reason.