# How to specify the Dirichlet boundary condition in mathematica DSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations

I want to specify the following Dirichlet condition for obtaining an analytic solution for the Laplace equation in mathemaitca:
$$u(x, 0) = 0, u(x, 1) = 10, u(0, y) = 0, u(1, y) = 10$$
How to write it?

Comment: Did you look on `DirichletCondition`?

Comment: yes, but I don't understand how to input these conditions. I have tried it but it doesn't work, something's wrong with the format!

Comment: see [how-to-use-dirichletcondition-with-dsolve-and-not-just-ndsolvevalue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189795/how-to-use-dirichletcondition-with-dsolve-and-not-just-ndsolvevalue)

Answer (score 1):

One way could be

```
bc = {u[x, 0] == 0, u[x, 1] == 10, u[0, y] == 0, u[1, y] == 10};
pde = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0
sol = DSolveValue[{pde, bc}, u[x, y], {x, y}];
sol /. K[1] -> n
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To plot it

```
sol0 = Activate[sol /. Infinity -> 40]; (*more terms->more accurate*)
Plot3D[Evaluate[sol0], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Numerically

```
bc = {u[x, 0] == 0, u[x, 1] == 10, u[0, y] == 0, u[1, y] == 10};
pde = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, bc}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you Nasser, I have already tried this approach, however, I was wondering how to use the function DirichletCondition!

Comment: @devanshushekhar  I could not get DirichletCondition to work with `DSolve`. See [how-to-use-dirichletcondition-with-dsolve-and-not-just-ndsolvevalue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189795/how-to-use-dirichletcondition-with-dsolve-and-not-just-ndsolvevalue)

Answer (score 1):

Looking onto the [example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirichletCondition.html) from the MMA help system:

```
s=NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x <= -0.3], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, x >= 0.35]}, u, {x, y} \[Element] 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]

Plot3D[s[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]]
```

[image]

There are two `DirichletCondition` objects that define `u` at bottom and top arcs of the boundary (the circle defining used `Disk`)